# How can I find out which PHP script a process is running in Linux?

Tags: php, linux, apache, process

Running Linux, Apache, PHP 5.3 with FastCGI Handler.

Is it possible to find out the script that is being executed for a linux process? I've been searching on google and haven't been able to find anything useful.

Answer (score 57):

```
pstree | grep php
ps aux | grep php
ps xuww | grep php
...
```

Comment: If you are running php as Apache module you won't see anything in this way, you can just see Apache processes

Comment: You need to use ps aux | grep apache for the apache processes

Answer (score 15):

Just use:

```
ps aux | grep php
```

Shows you php scripts running with their paths.

Answer (score 12):

In one SSH window:

```
telnet localhost 80
```

In another, find out the port number:

```
lsof -p `pidof telnet`
```

Then, to find out the process:

```
netstat -nap | grep {port}
```

And finally:

```
strace -o /tmp/output -f -r -s4096 -p {PID}
```

Will show you **every process** which runs when you make a httpd connection to the server in order.  If you search through this list you'll find your PHP script.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you can try this!

```
ps ax | grep *.php
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pgrep` for that, e.g.

```
pgrep -l php
```

or:

```
pgrep php && echo PHP script is running || echo PHP script is NOT running
```