# PHP and MySQL - Lot of queries causing timeout of 300 seconds

Tags: php, mysql

I got a PHP application that causes performance issues with MySQL. What happens is this: After the database entries extend a certain amount; it starts to randomly timeout the PHP page for 300 seconds.

I know I have to rewrite my code, since it is messy, out-dated, and I'm basically running a lot of queries which could be much more efficient.

But, I'm very curious what is able to cause this, and if there is a short-term solution for this. The php application works perfectly, but after browsing some pages with the results of the query behaving like it should, sometimes the load-time changes to 300 seconds. After which the page with database results show perfectly. After that I'm able to view some pages again, after which the process randomly starts over. During the 300 seconds the page is loading, the SQL processlist shows the command "Sleep" for the full loading time, with no query attached.

Comment: Do you mean that the problem occurs SOMETIMES and sometimes not?

Comment: @Voitcus, correct, the problem happens every couple of pageloads. No logic behind that, sometimes it happens after 1 pageload, sometimes after 10, etc.

Comment: BY default, PHP.ini settings specify that if the page has not finished to be processed by the server, a timeout occurs. You can change this value using : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: Maybe the program opens a new db connection for each query and doesn't close it so MySQL halts?

Comment: Does your `MySQL` db log anything weird, and/or what does its slow-query log say?

Comment: Weird enough my MySQL doesn't log a thing about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the problem is really MySQL related, you could try to assign more memory to MySQL server and see if performance improves. See the "huge" my.cnf configuration here:

http://fts.ifac.cnr.it/cgi-bin/dwww/usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.0/examples/my-huge.cnf.gz

Also, if you don't need InnoDB features but your database is InnoDB, you can switch to MyISAM and gain some performance.

You should also check session locking and collision, this sometimes can create timeouts. You should release session as soon as you've read/written data on it because the session file stays locked until you close the session or the script has ended.

Comment: This might be a good path to follow. The app times out during the browser session and can't be accessed from that session during that time, though closing and reopening the browser (or visiting the app in another browser) resolves the problem till the timeout occurs again.

Comment: Spot on! Thank you very much =) The problem was resolved after I called session_write_close(); after i finished checking the user session at the start of the script.

Answer (score 0):

If the process list doesn't show running queries, than the problem is probably located at your application, and not at MySQL. Take a look at this: [How can I find out which PHP script a process is running in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468332/how-can-i-find-out-which-php-script-a-process-is-running-in-linux).